# Validate HTTP GET requests with fluent validation .net core

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have fluent validation integrated which is working fine for POST requests model validation

But what is the best approach to attach validator to GET requests?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetV2Async(Constants.Status status, int? cafeId)
```

My current validators for my POST requests look like this:

```
 public CafeAddressRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is required");
        RuleFor(x => x.AddressLine1).NotEmpty().WithMessage("AddressLine1 is required");
    }
```

Comment: no you can't, https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/337

Comment: What is your `Constants.Status`?The fluent validation could work well with get request.Please share more code about how did you configure fluent validation and what is the version of your asp.net core?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

Model:

```
public class Status
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(Status status, int? cafeId)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    return Ok("Validate pass");
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllers()
       .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CafeAddressRequestValidator>());
```

Custom FluentValidation:

```
public class CafeAddressRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<Status>
{
    
    public CafeAddressRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is required");
        RuleFor(x => x.AddressLine1).NotEmpty().WithMessage("AddressLine1 is required");
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

If you want to pass the validation,send request like:`https://localhost:portNumber/yourMethod?status.name=dsfsd&status.AddressLine1=sdf`:

[image]

Comment: It helped thank you! Sorry for the delayed response I thought I had responded :)