# How to use FluentValidation When() with DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, .net, data-annotations, fluentvalidation

We are removing the use of FluentValidation from our project. We will use DataAnnotations.

We couldn't find any alternative code for using "when()".

Example using FluentValidation When():

```
public class IndividualEditVoValidator : LayeredValidator<IndividualEditVo>
  {
    public IndividualEditVoValidator()
    {
      RuleFor(v => v.Name).NotEmpty()
        .When(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.LastName))
        .WithMessage(m => Errors.NameNullCheckMessage);
    }
  }
```

for example "string.IsNullOrEmpty" is used here.

Is there an alternative to this in DataAnnotations? or how can i do it?

Comment: Add Hoc, I'd probabl try a [CustomValidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute?view=net-5.0) ... but actually, I prefer FLuentValidation. Out of curiosity: what made the decision against it?

Comment: We are migrating the project from .net framework to .net5. [Validator(typeof(...))] is not supported in the new version of FluentValidation. It has its own Validate() method instead of ModelState.IsValid. unfortunately it makes more sense to remove it since the project also uses DataAnnotations. otherwise my preference would be FluentValidation.

Comment: FluentValidation can be added to the http request pipeline and populate the model state, you don't need to manually invoke the validate method.

Comment: wonderful! Like here? -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62926544/5435600

Comment: That's one way of doing it though as its part of the http request pipeline, if validation fails it won't make it to the controller code - processing will end at that point in the pipeline and the model state in the response will already contain the errors